# How can you handle an IN sub-query with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm a bit stuck on this. Basically I want to do something like the following SQL query in LINQ to SQL:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM Foo f
WHERE f.FooId IN (
    SELECT fb.FooId
    FROM FooBar fb
    WHERE fb.BarId = 1000
)
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql). Basically, if you want to get the equivalent of IN, you need to construct an inner query first, and then use the Contains() method. Here's my attempt at translating:

```
var innerQuery = from fb in FoorBar where fb.BarId = 1000 select fb.FooId;
var result = from f in Foo where innerQuery.Contains(f.FooId) select f;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - that was just what I needed.
Thanks to everyone else for their answers as well.

Comment: You might have better performance with constructing a Dictionary with the first query, as the Contains() call in the second query can then be done in O(1) as opposed to O(n).

Comment: Daren, LINQ to SQL will be transformed to SQL query. Dictionary will be useful when iterating over objects collection.

Comment: @Samuel_Jack 
 
How can I use this in a LinqDatasource?

Comment: The link is now dead and the answer is much less useful. It would've been better if this answer contained more information from the linked article, precisely to prevent this situation.

Comment: Tank you so much :)

Answer (score 88):

## General way to implement IN in LINQ to SQL

```
var q = from t1 in table1
        let t2s = from t2 in table2
                  where <Conditions for table2>
                  select t2.KeyField
        where t2s.Contains(t1.KeyField)
        select t1;
```

## General way to implement EXISTS in LINQ to SQL

```
var q = from t1 in table1
        let t2s = from t2 in table2
                  where <Conditions for table2>
                  select t2.KeyField
        where t2s.Any(t1.KeyField)
        select t1;
```

Comment: Quick and to the point - great answer. Even though building the inner query in a separate statement is definitely clear, might as well know how to do it inline. Thanks!

Comment: @aku Is this method preferable to @Samuel Jack's method?

Comment: This is much more readable than method chaining syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for query!! Minor observation: In vb the query statement to the right of t2s = should be wrapped in brackets. I am in vs2013

Answer (score 3):

```
from f in Foo
    where f.FooID ==
        (
            FROM fb in FooBar
            WHERE fb.BarID == 1000
            select fb.FooID

        )
    select f;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using two separate steps:

```
// create a Dictionary / Set / Collection fids first
var fids = (from fb in FooBar
            where fb.BarID = 1000
            select new { fooID = fb.FooID, barID = fb.BarID })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.fooID, x => x.barID);

from f in Foo
where fids.HasKey(f.FooId)
select f
```

Answer (score 1):

// create a Dictionary / Set / Collection fids first

[Find Other Artilces](http://www.doyouknow.in/How.aspx)

```
var fids = (from fb in FooBar
            where fb.BarID = 1000
            select new { fooID = fb.FooID, barID = fb.BarID })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.fooID, x => x.barID);

from f in Foo
where fids.HasKey(f.FooId)
select f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var fooids = from fb in foobar where fb.BarId=1000 select fb.fooID
var ff = from f in foo where f.FooID = fooids select f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foos = Foo.Where<br>
( f => FooBar.Where(fb.BarId == 1000).Select(fb => fb.FooId).Contains(f.FooId));
```

Answer (score 0):

// create a Dictionary / Set / Collection fids first

[Find Other Artilces](http://www.doyouknow.in/DoYouKnow/How.aspx)

```
var fids = (from fb in FooBar where fb.BarID = 1000 select new { fooID = fb.FooID, barID = fb.BarID }) .ToDictionary(x => x.fooID, x => x.barID);

from f in Foo where fids.HasKey(f.FooId) select f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from f in foo
where f.FooID equals model.FooBar.SingleOrDefault(fBar => fBar.barID = 1000).FooID
select new
{
f.Columns
};
```