# TSQL to LINQ conversion reference?

Tags: linq, t-sql

I'm trying to find a good reference to help me convert this TSQL statement to Linq:

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM ProductCategories WHERE CatID = 23)
```

I can't find anywhere that references how to do the WHERE "IN" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not *exactly* a TSQL to LINQ reference, I have found the [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) page on MSDN helpful for this purpose.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51339/how-can-you-handle-an-in-sub-query-with-linq-to-sql)

Comment: Thanks - is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#intersect2  what I'm looking for? TSQL "IN" = Linq "Intersect"?

Comment: Ooops - I just now saw your "this related question" which gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
var qry = from c in Categories
          where (from pc in ProductCategories where pc.CatID = 23 select pc.ProductID).Contains(c.ProductID)
          select c;
```

I don't know if there is a direct translation of the IN WHERE part in *LinqToSQL* (didn't found any reference) but I replaced that with a `Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

Using extension methods...

```
var productIDs = context.ProductCategories
                        .Where( c => c.CatID == 23 )
                        .Select( c => c.ProductID );
var categories = context.Categories
                        .Where( c => productIDS.Contains( c => c.ProductID ) );
```

**EDIT**: 101 Linq Samples is a pretty good reference for simple things.  For more complicated stuff I find that I usually have to resort to Google.  FYI, if you want to search StackOverflow, I've found that it works better to use google and specify `site: stackoverflow.com`.  YMMV.