# Is there any work-around for NHibernate-to-LINQ not supporting subqueries?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I know LINQ-to-NHibernate currently does not support sub-queries (http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx).

Is there any workaround about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

linq-to-nh DOES support sub queries in where clause. It is exact thing I needed. I was wrong with my previous answer. Both martijnboland and Stefan Steinegger were right. To see how you do sub-queries in linq-to-nh see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51339/how-can-you-handle-an-in-sub-query-with-linq-to-sql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138093/dynamic-linq-to-nhibernate-query-problem). There is also [limitations](http://www.mail-archive.com/nhusers@googlegroups.com/msg11393.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think the workaround is simply to use HQL or Criteria.

Comment: Unfortunately Criteria does not support subqueries too. Indeed LINQ-to-NHibernate is based on ICriteria and this disability origins from ICriteria itself.

Comment: Criteria **DOES** support subqueries. It's built with `DetachedCriteria` and added with `.Add(Subqueries.Blah(subquery))` (where `Blah` is `Exists` or `PropertyIn` or something like this)

Comment: after a long long time I'm convinced that you were right. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with nhibernate to linq but i'm sure that you can translate almost any subquery to a join

Comment: Unfortunately it does not support joins too!

Comment: Note that there is a difference between subqueries in the select and subqueries in the where clause: subqueries in the where clause are supported and work fine (Any(), Count() etc.)

Comment: Dear martijn, I'm going to use "select subqueries"

Comment: @martijn, After a long long time I realized that the sub-query that I needed was sub query in `where` clause. You were right.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a two part LINQ query as a work around. A LINQ-to-NHibernate for not related sub query section and a LINQ-to-Object for sub query related section of the query. Please see http://afsharm.blogspot.com/2010/03/dealing-with-subqueries-in-linq-to.html for more detail.