# Dynamic linq-to-nhibernate query problem

Tags: linq, nhibernate, subquery, linq-to-nhibernate, dynamicquery

Suppose I have classes `Foo` and `Bar` as follow:

```
public class Foo
{
public string F1 {set; get;}
public string F2 {set; get;}

public Bar ContainerBar {set; get;}
}

public class Bar
{
public string B1 {set; get;}
public string B2 {set; get;}

public List<Foo> Foos {set; get;}
}
```

Following linq query has errors saying that `foo` does not contain a property named `F1`.

```
var query = from foo in session.Linq<Foo>()
                 select foo.ContainerBar;

query = query.Where(foo => foo.F1 == "abcdef");
```

I know `foo` in second statement is really a `Bar` because query selects `ContainerBar`.

The question is know how can I add a dynamic where clause to query without changing origianl query? Final goal is to have sub-queries with linq-to-nhibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from foo in session.Linq<Foo>()
                 select foo.ContainerBar;

query = query.Where(foo => foo.F1 == "abcdef");
```

Your "query" object is now an IQueryAble of ContainerBar's
So when you do the Where( foo => foo.F1 == "abcdef" ), it's done on IQueryable, so no F1 property.

You should do:

```
var bars = from foo in session.Linq<Foo>()
            where foo.F1 == "abcdef"
            select foo.ContainerBar;
```

Or:

```
var q = session.Linq<Foo>();

// if some condition
q = q.Where( foo => foo.F1 == "abcdef" );

var bars = q.Select( foo => foo.ContainerBar );
```

Comment: but where clause must be added at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NHibernate 3.0? The first query doesn't work for me (NHibernate 2.1.2.4000, invalid cast). However, it looks like you're trying to get all Bars that have Foos, which can be done like this...

```
IQueryable<Bar> bars = Session
    .Linq<Bar>()
    .Where(bar => bar.Foos.Any());
```

Now that you have the Bars, in your later code you can check F1 like this...

```
var result = bars
    .Where(bar => bar.Foos.Any(foo => foo.F1 == "b"));
```

Comment: No, I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2