# Entity Framework LINQ - Subquery with Group By

Tags: linq, entity-framework, group-by, subquery

I am trying to achieve a query which includes a subquery which itself includes grouping.

I based my code from answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51339/how-can-you-handle-an-in-sub-query-with-linq-to-sql)

The purpose of the code is to perform a simple de-duplication of the 'person' table based on the email address and return the latest person row.

```
var innerQuery = (from p in db.Person
                              join r in db.Registration on p equals r.Person
                              join e in db.EventDetail on r.EventDetail equals e
                              where e.Client.ClientID == clientID
                              group p by p.Email into g
                              select g.Max(p => p.PersonID));

var query = (from p2 in db.Person where innerQuery.Contains(p2.PersonID) select p2);
```

When the query is attempted to execute, I get the following error message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'Boolean
>   Contains[Int32](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32],
>   Int32)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

I have tested the innerquery and it just returns a list of ints as expected, but the query fails with the above message.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `query` just a join?

```
var query = from p2 in db.Person
            join iq in innerQuery on p2.PersonID equals iq
            select p2;
```

I'm not sure about `= iq` part but I don't usually use that syntax sorry - in the other form it would be

```
.Join(innerQuery, p2 => p2.PersonId, iq => iq, (p2, iq) => p2);
```

for the join and the select.

Comment: Works if adjust to:

from p2 in db.Person
join iq in innerQuery on p2.PersonID equals iq
select p2

Thanks.