# Rewriting a SQL with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have this `SQL`:

```
select * from ADDRESSES where ZIPCODE ='66210'and ADDRESS_K in 
       (select ADDRESS_K from GROUPADDRESS where GROUP_K in 
       (select GROUP_K from GROUPS where NPI = 'groupnpi' and TAXID = 'grouptin') 
        and ADDRESSTYPE_RTK = '_REI0PVM65')
```

I want to rewrite it in `LINQ`

Can someone help with  converting it to `LINQ`? That's as far as I could get.

Comment: You have to run the query *on* something (e.g., with using Linq to Entities). Where are you running it on? Do you have for example a `dBContext.ADDRESSES`, `dBContext.GROUPADDRESS` and `dBContext.GROUPS` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not tested but should give you a good start (this helped [How can you handle an IN sub-query with LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51339/how-can-you-handle-an-in-sub-query-with-linq-to-sql))

```
var innerInnerQuery = from g in GROUPS
                      where NPI == "roupnpi" 
                          && TAXID == "grouptin"
                          && ADDRESSTYPE_RTK == "_REI0PVM65"
                      select g.GROUP_K;
var innerQuery = from ga in GROUPADDRESS
                 where innerInnerQuery.Contains(ga.GROUP_K)
                 select ga.ADDRESS_K;
var query = from a in ADDRESSES
            where ZIPCODE == "66210"
                && innerQuery.Contains(a.ADDRESS_K)
            select a;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I could come up with...
Please let me know if it works

```
var innerQuery = from Group_K in GroupAddress
                  where Group_K ==
                         (
                              from iq in Groups
                              where iq.NPI.Contains("groupnpi")
                              where iq.TAXID == "grouptin"
                              where iq.ADDRESSTYPE_RTK == "REI0PVM65"
                              select iq.NPI
                         )
                         select Group_K.Address_K;

        var result = from a in addresses
                     where a.ZipCode.Contains("groupnpi")
                     where a == innerQuery
                     select a;
```