# Convert SQL subquery to LINQ format which contains IN, DISTINCT keywords

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Sir/Ma'am  I want to convert the below mentioned SQL query into LINQ how can I achieve this.

```
select * from dbo.Main as M 
where M.ApplicationId in 
(select distinct R.ApplicationId from tblRecomSanctionedDetail R 
where R.UpdateByUserId = 1011 )
```

tried using my limited knowledge with LINQ but could not get the output.

Comment: `DISTINCT` doesn't do anything here, so you can remove it.  Check this answer for `IN()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51339/how-can-you-handle-an-in-sub-query-with-linq-to-sql

Comment: Thanks Aaron I was able to get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have anywhere to test this at the moment but I think roughly it would be something like…

```
var applicationIds = tblRecomSanctionedDetailQueryable.Where(x => x.UpdateByUserId == 1011).Select(x => x.ApplicationId);
var result = mainQueryable.Where(x => applicationIds.Contains(x.ApplicationId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Timovski I was able to get the desired result using this query also